# How to quote a paper with $\Sigma^m_n$ in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a paper with a title as $\Sigma^4_3 Production \ and \Pi^3_2 Alienation$. How should I do this in bibtex if I may?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use properly math mode and braces to avoid case changing

```
title = {{$\Sigma^4_3$} {Production} and  {$\Pi^3_2$} Alienation},
```